# Rotate a PDF from InAppBrowser

Tags: ios, pdf, cordova, rotation, inappbrowser

So I was able to integrate [InAppBrowser-CE](http://github.com/cemerson/cordova-inappbrowser-ce) this plugin which works amazingly to display PDF's from a specified window size and give transparency, but now I am trying to figure out how to rotate the PDF. I want to add a rotation tool (similar to the photo library in iOS) but dont know where to start at. I saw something about image rotation tool, but wasnt sure if it applied to a pdf file, and I don't want to keep at something that doesn't work (i.e. using iFrame instead of InAppBrowser to display PDFs) any help is much appreciated. Here is just a sample of how the PDF is called to give you some insight.

This is from HTML to call it to open:

```
 <button onclick="window.open('http://www.free.woodworking-plans.org/images/ranch-house-7161/ranch-house-floor-plan-o.jpg','_blank','vw=685,vh=650,vx=40,vy=40');">Change my size</button>
```

And here is how the PDF is opened (from xcode CDVInAppBrowser.m)

```
- (void)openInInAppBrowser:(NSURL*)url withOptions:(NSString*)options
{

    if (self.inAppBrowserViewController == nil) {
        NSString* originalUA = [CDVUserAgentUtil originalUserAgent];
        self.inAppBrowserViewController = [[CDVInAppBrowserViewController alloc] initWithUserAgent:originalUA prevUserAgent:[self.commandDelegate userAgent]];
        self.inAppBrowserViewController.navigationDelegate = self;

        if ([self.viewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CDVScreenOrientationDelegate)]) {
            self.inAppBrowserViewController.orientationDelegate = (UIViewController <CDVScreenOrientationDelegate>*)self.viewController;
        }
    }

    // set pointer to this viewcontroller for later use
    iabvc = self.inAppBrowserViewController;

    CDVInAppBrowserOptions* browserOptions = [CDVInAppBrowserOptions parseOptions:options];
    [self.inAppBrowserViewController showLocationBar:browserOptions.location];
    [self.inAppBrowserViewController showToolBar:browserOptions.toolbar];
```

....

```
- (id)initWithUserAgent:(NSString*)userAgent prevUserAgent:(NSString*)prevUserAgent
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        _userAgent = userAgent;
        _prevUserAgent = prevUserAgent;
        _webViewDelegate = [[CDVWebViewDelegate alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

        [self createViews];
    }

    return self;
}
```

And here is what the tools section looks like,

```
self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, (self.view.bounds.size.height - TOOLBAR_HEIGHT), self.view.bounds.size.width, TOOLBAR_HEIGHT)];
    self.toolbar.alpha = 1.000;
    self.toolbar.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    self.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    self.toolbar.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
    self.toolbar.clipsToBounds = NO;
    self.toolbar.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    self.toolbar.contentStretch = CGRectFromString(@"{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}");
    self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
    self.toolbar.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    self.toolbar.opaque = NO;
    self.toolbar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a rotate button then added this below,

.h

```
  //header - add 'int counter'
@interface CDVInAppBrowserViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
@private
    NSString* _userAgent;
    NSString* _prevUserAgent;
    NSInteger _userAgentLockToken;
    CDVWebViewDelegate* _webViewDelegate;
    int counter;
}
```

.m

```
//Add this to the top of the .m file
#define DegreesToRadians(X) ((X) * M_PI / 180.0)

...

 //reference
- (id)initWithUserAgent:(NSString*)userAgent prevUserAgent:(NSString*)prevUserAgent
{
    counter = 0;

...

//create Rotate Button
NSString* rotateString = @"Rotate";
self.RotateButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:rotateString style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goRotate:)];
self.RotateButton.enabled = YES;
self.RotateButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

....

//action - sender
-(IBAction)goRotate:(id)sender
{           counter ++;  float angle = (counter%3)*90;
            [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            self.webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(angle));
            [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```